# Regular Expression to remove whitespace in the middle of a string before a character

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to capture the "Some Company Name" from the string below

```
@@VALUE= Some Company Name            @@
```

But without the trailing spaces before the final @@.

I'm receiving this data as a pipe so I am trying to use a regex replace in Perl to replace this part, so the final result would look like:

```
@@VALUE=Some Company Name@@
```

I can match the leading space before the company name, but my match for the company name is always:

```
"Some Company Name            "
```

Currently using this Regex:

```
(\@\@VALUE=)(\s)([^@]*)
```

Removing trailing white space would be easy if not for the @@ on the end.

Comment: `\@\@CUSTOMER=\s*(.+?)\s*\@\@`

Comment: Why does your regex contain `"@@CUSTOMER="`, while your example inputs contain `"@@VALUE=`? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: @Matthew That looks like it would have awful performance if there is a long string without `@@` at the end.

Comment: @Matthew - that worked perfectly. I was taking completely the wrong approach.

Comment: @Matthew I tested your regex against the string `'@@CUSTOMER= hello? ' . (' ' x 50000) . "\nX\@\@"`. It took several seconds to finish (and fail), eating 100% CPU. That's pretty bad.

Comment: @melpomene thanks for the insight, I very rarely use regex for anything performance critical personally, but it's good to know about its limitations.  Of course if OP has such a scenario then it would be advisable to pick another solution.

Comment: @Matthew It's not an inherent limitation of regexes. Just use a non-stupid^W less awful pattern.

Comment: Show me where the regex touched you

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to remove all spaces before the final `@@`, that's just

```
s/\s+\@\@$/\@\@/;
```

I'm not sure why you need to match anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `\s+(?=@@$)`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KR9gI3/1)

[Perl Demo](https://ideone.com/3Z2RXV)

Answer (score 0):

or use perl regex lazy mode

```
$s = '@@VALUE= Some Company Name       @@'
$s =~ s/@@VALUE=\s*(.+?)\s*@@\s*$/$1/
print $s
```